# Is it possible to read Maven pom.xml properties from SBT?

Tags: sbt

I wanted to write something there but I couldn't pass quality check for this simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this `sbt` plugin from [GitHub](https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin).

Simply described as:

> A sbt plugin which reads project definitions from pom.xml. By using this plugin, you can just update your dependencies(or whatever) in pom.xml, and reload on your SBT console. Cool!

Add the plugin to your `plugins.sbt` file and go wild.

Comment: To make it work I had to add resolver and use different version instead of 0.1.2 as suggested in documentation. project/plugins.sbt becomes:  
`resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
  
addSbtPlugin("com.github.shivawu" % "sbt-maven-plugin" % "0.1.3-SNAPSHOT")`

Comment: Further there is not artifact for Scala 2.11 but it seems to work. Though I had to keep externalPom() call in build.sbt because without it didn't load dependencies based on pom.xml. I don't know why. But by scala.version and scala.bin are picked up by the plugin. I haven't tried other properties defined in pom.xml as it is unclear to me how should I refer to them in build.sbt, there is little documentation.

Comment: F.e if I have <avro.version>1.7.7</avro.version> defined in pom.xml properties. How do I refer to it in build.sbt when sbt-maven-plugin is used?

I need it to execute sbt avro plugin and set the version for it which I would like keep in sync with pom.xml.

Comment: I'm looking into this now, If I am able to find something I'll tell you.

Comment: That would be great as I would love to use SBT on our projects though I need to introduce it seamlessly with Maven for now.